# Why is my JDBC Kafka Connector not picking up new events or creating a topic after creating a source connector?

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, ksqldb

We currently have a connector up and running according to our ksqlDB Server:

```
 ENTITY_CHANGE  | SOURCE | io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector | RUNNING (1/1 tasks RUNNING)
```

Though a jdbc_entity_change topic is not generated by our source connector like it is when we create this connector locally. The Kafka Connect server is embedded onto our ksqlDB server.

```
CREATE SOURCE CONNECTOR entity_change WITH (
    'connector.class'          = 'io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector',
    'connection.url'           = redacted,
    'connection.user'          = redacted,
    'connection.password'      = redacted,
    'topic.prefix'             = 'jdbc_',
    'mode'                     = 'timestamp+incrementing',
    'numeric.mapping'          = 'best_fit',
    'incrementing.column.name' = 'id',
    'timestamp.column.name'    = 'last_modified',
    'key'                      = 'id',
    'key.converter'            = 'org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.LongConverter',
    'query'                    = 'redacted'
);
```

We've confirmed that we have connectivity to our database since our database throws an error when we supply incorrect credentials.

Logs on ksqldb server:

```
2023-03-13 11:09:03 ksqldb-server              | [2023-03-13 18:09:03,164] INFO Instantiated connector ENTITY_CHANGE with version 10.0.0 of type class io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:322)
2023-03-13 11:09:03 ksqldb-server              | [2023-03-13 18:09:03,166] INFO Finished creating connector ENTITY_CHANGE (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:347)
2023-03-13 11:09:03 ksqldb-server              | [2023-03-13 18:09:03,172] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=ksql-connect-cluster] Finished starting connectors and tasks (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:1687)
2023-03-13 11:09:03 ksqldb-server              | [2023-03-13 18:09:03,174] INFO Starting JDBC Source Connector (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector:69)
2023-03-13 11:09:03 ksqldb-server              | [2023-03-13 18:09:03,182] INFO JdbcSourceConnectorConfig values:
2023-03-13 11:09:03 ksqldb-server              |        batch.max.rows = 100
2023-03-13 11:09:03 ksqldb-server              |        catalog.pattern = null
2023-03-13 11:09:03 ksqldb-server              |        connection.attempts = 3
2023-03-13 11:09:03 ksqldb-server              |        connection.backoff.ms = 10000
2023-03-13 11:09:03 ksqldb-server              |        connection.password = [hidden]
2023-03-13 11:09:03 ksqldb-server              |        connection.url = jdbc:redacted?zeroDateTimeBehavior=round
2023-03-13 11:09:03 ksqldb-server              |        connection.user = redacted
2023-03-13 11:09:03 ksqldb-server              |        db.timezone = UTC
2023-03-13 11:09:03 ksqldb-server              |        dialect.name =
2023-03-13 11:09:03 ksqldb-server              |        incrementing.column.name = id
2023-03-13 11:09:03 ksqldb-server              |        mode = timestamp+incrementing
2023-03-13 11:09:03 ksqldb-server              |        numeric.mapping = best_fit
2023-03-13 11:09:03 ksqldb-server              |        numeric.precision.mapping = false
2023-03-13 11:09:03 ksqldb-server              |        poll.interval.ms = 5000
2023-03-13 11:09:03 ksqldb-server              |        query = redacted
2023-03-13 11:09:03 ksqldb-server              |        query.suffix =
2023-03-13 11:09:03 ksqldb-server              |        quote.sql.identifiers = ALWAYS
2023-03-13 11:09:03 ksqldb-server              |        schema.pattern = null
2023-03-13 11:09:03 ksqldb-server              |        table.blacklist = []
2023-03-13 11:09:03 ksqldb-server              |        table.poll.interval.ms = 60000
2023-03-13 11:09:03 ksqldb-server              |        table.types = [TABLE]
2023-03-13 11:09:03 ksqldb-server              |        table.whitelist = []
2023-03-13 11:09:03 ksqldb-server              |        timestamp.column.name = [last_modified]
2023-03-13 11:09:03 ksqldb-server              |        timestamp.delay.interval.ms = 0
2023-03-13 11:09:03 ksqldb-server              |        timestamp.initial = null
2023-03-13 11:09:03 ksqldb-server              |        topic.prefix = jdbc_entity_change
2023-03-13 11:09:03 ksqldb-server              |        validate.non.null = true
```

Whenever we modify any fields that should be picked up my SQL query in the query field of this source connector nothing is picked up nor is a topic created for this source connector to start emitting events to.

Since creating the source connector does not generate a topic as it does locally, I have even attempted to manually create a topic and directly link the source connector to the topic via the topic.prefix field. This also does not work.

Does anybody have any ideas about what could be potentially misconfigured?

Comment: Do your queries actually update the `last_modified` column?

Comment: Yes, I run an update query to modify the last_modified column, like so: UPDATE entity SET last_modified = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP; COMMIT;

Comment: The above update statement works (jdbc_entity_change topic has new events) when I am running all my Kafka infra locally.

Comment: If it works "locally", but not elsewhere, that sounds like a networking/connection issue in your own network, rather than your configs shown here

Comment: ```[Producer clientId=connector-producer-ENTITY_CHANGE-0] Cancelled in-flight METADATA request with correlation id= ``` Seems to be showing up in my ksqldb server logs. I have set my embedded kafka connect authentication, the same way I am authenticating with my ksqldb server to my brokers. I'm thinking this might be related to the root cause of the issue.

Comment: I know typically there is a producer and consumer configuration for kafka connect, should I have to set this up for my embedded kafka connect?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? These are already configured for you, and there is no separate property file for setting these, only the ksql properties. The metadata requests aren't necessarily an error. There would be a more explicit network exception stacktrace if you were having connection issues

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252557/discussion-between-farhan-islam-and-onecricketeer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that I needed to supply authentication details at the for Kafka Connect at the producer and consumer level on top of the base authentication level. This is pretty silly that this was the root cause and this is what you need for your brokers to be able to communicate with your kafka connect embedded server. This doesn't seem to be documented anywhere in ksqlDB / Kafka documentation.

You need to provide the following properties for this to work if your Kafka broker has authentication enabled.

```
KSQL_CONNECT_SECURITY_PROTOCOL=SASL_PLAINTEXT
KSQL_CONNECT_SASL_MECHANISM=SCRAM-SHA-256
KSQL_CONNECT_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG=
KSQL_CONNECT_CONSUMER_SASL_MECHANISM=SCRAM-SHA-256
KSQL_CONNECT_CONSUMER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL=SASL_PLAINTEXT
KSQL_CONNECT_CONSUMER_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG= 
KSQL_CONNECT_PRODUCER_SASL_MECHANISM=SCRAM-SHA-256
KSQL_CONNECT_PRODUCER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL=SASL_PLAINTEXT
KSQL_CONNECT_PRODUCER_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG=
```

These are Docker-specific configurations FYI.
If you were using a configuration file it would be in the following syntax

```
consumer.sasl.jaas.config=
```

Comment: These properties aren't ksql specific (ignoring Docker container specifics). Setting producer/consumer configs for Connect is documentated at https://kafka.apache.org/documentation ; you could do the same at the connector level with values like `consumer.override.sasl.jaas.config=...`